# Type system for function composition

Tags: javascript, typescript

How would I add types for `compose`?
The problem basically boils down to writing the types for this:

```
const compose = (...funcs) => x => funcs.reduce((acc, func) => func(acc), x);
```

and using it:

```
compose(x => x + 1, x => x * 2)(3);
```

In this example, the type of compose is inferred to:

```
const compose: (...funcs: any[]) => (x: any) => any
```

Which is just a bunch of `any`...

Is there a good way to add types to `compose`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is not possible to type such a function to accept any number of functions, we can write a version of `compose` that has overloads of up to a given number of functions. For most practical uses it should be enough allow composition of up to 5 functions, and we can always add more overloads as the need arises.

I also added an overload for when the types are not different and we only have one type that is being processed throughout compose. This allows an arbitrary number of functions to be passed in if the parameter type and return type are the same.

```
function compose<A, B, C, D, E, F>(fn: (p: A) => B, fn2: (p: B) => C, fn3: (p: C) => D, fn4: (p: D) => E, fn5: (p: E) => F): (p: A) => F
function compose<A, B, C, D, E>(fn: (p: A) => B, fn2: (p: B) => C, fn3: (p: C) => D, fn4: (p: D) => E): (p: A) => E
function compose<A, B, C, D>(fn: (p: A) => B, fn2: (p: B) => C, fn3: (p: C) => D): (p: A) => D
function compose<A, B, C>(fn: (p: A) => B, fn2: (p: B) => C): (p: A) => C
function compose<T>(...funcs: Array<(p: T) => T>) : (p: T) => T // Special case of parameter and return having the same type
function compose(...funcs: Array<(p: any) => any>) {
    return (x: any) => funcs.reduce((acc, func) => func(acc), x)
};

// Usage
// First argument type must be specified, rest are inferred correctly
let fn = compose((x : number) => x + 1, x => x * 2); // fn will be (p: number) => number
let d = fn(3); // d will be number 

let fn2 = compose((x : number) => x + 1, x => x * 2, x=> x.toString(), x => x.toLowerCase()); // fn will be (p: number) => string and we get intelisense and type safety in each function 

// Any number of functions but a single type
let fnMany = compose((x : number) => x + 1, x => x * 2, x => x * 2, x => x * 2, x => x * 2, x => x * 2, x => x * 2);
```

Comment: That's amazing! Probably as close as we can get to a "general" solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could introduce some type information, I typically recommend an iterative approach to this, for example this early version isn't very flexible - but results in the final type being correct:

```
interface Composer {
    (...funcs: { (arg: any): any }[]): (arg: any) => number;
}

const compose: Composer = (...funcs) => x => funcs.reduce((acc, func) => func(acc), x);

// result: number
const result = compose(x => x + 1, x => x * 2)(3);
```

You can iterate this towards your particular use. For example, it may be that the final type needs to be a generic type, so you could upgrade `Composer` to `Composer<T>`. Or you may want to make the intermediate types less permissive (they can currently be any type, but you can improve that too).

Ultimately, it is up to you to decide where to fix types, or introduce dynamic types, or to stop caring about types entirely within the `Composer` type.

Comment: Well done! I like the idea of starting with `any`s everywhere (four of them) in `(...funcs: {(y:any):any}[]):(x:any)=>any` and then iterate each of the `any` s to get as specific as you need. Making Composer generic is also a great idea. Without `any` in the funcs array though, you'd need all the functions to have the same type, but that just might be okay.

Comment: Thanks! I actually wrote something similar, gave composer a generic with default to any so the developer can choose if she wants to explicitly give it a final type:

const compose = <T = any>(...funcs) => (x: any): T => funcs.reduce((acc, func) => func(acc), x);
compose<number>(x => x + 1, x => x * 2)(3);

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.

Thinking outside of TypeScript for a moment and considering ML-type language with Hindley-Milner inference, the type of compose for two functions would be

```
compose2: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c
compose2 f g x = g(f x)
```

If you had three functions the type would be

```
compose3: (a->b) -> (b->c) -> (c->d) -> a -> d
```

And moving on

```
compose4: (a->b) -> (b->c) -> (c->d) -> (d->e) -> a -> e
```

You wish to write a compose function that takes an arbitrary number of functions (through the rest parameter) and then doing the composition through reduce. That is very cool, but you really can't lock down all the intermediate types of all the intermediate functions, because in general they can all be very, very, different.

The only way to deal with the flexibility of having an arbitrary number of functions that you wish to compose is to make (at least) all the intermediate functions have type

```
any -> any
```

Even if TypeScript had type variables as sophisticated as those languages in the ML family, the need for an arbitrary number of functions makes it not possible to avoid the `any`s (unless perhaps you want to restrict all functions to `a->a`, or in your particular TypeScript example `number=>number`).

Comment: Thank you. That's my intuition.
I assume you're correct but I'll leave the question open for a little while to see if there is some surprise solution to the problem.